# In node, using AJV, will null pass as an object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, schema, ajv

```
private: {
    type: "object",
    properties: {
      SSN: {type: "boolean"},
      DOB: {type: "boolean"},
    },
    additionalProperties: false,
    errorMessage: "private",
  },
```

The above is my schema. Note that the `required` field is not set, this means that an empty object will pass. But what about the value of `null`? `null` has `typoef` "object" in node.

So in AJV, will `null` pass the above schema validator?